# Weird thing happening in DataTable: Creating a backup DataTable

Tags: c#

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(); //I made this as a backup
        //add 3 columns
        dt1.Columns.Add();
        dt1.Columns.Add();
        dt1.Columns.Add();
        MessageBox.Show("Number of Columns in dt1: " + dt1.Columns.Count);
        DataTable dt2 = dt1;
        //I added another column just to say that that table changed
        dt2.Columns.Add();
        MessageBox.Show("Number of Columns in dt1: " + dt1.Columns.Count + "\r\nNumber of Columns in dt2: " + dt2.Columns.Count);
        //there's four columns now in both tables even though I added the column only in dt2
```

Why is this happening? And how do I change it so that the dt1 is not changed no matter what I do to dt2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# the only thing that creates a new object is the "new" keyword (or a method that uses the new keyword within it..) - you are just making a pointer (`dt2`) and pointing it at the same DataTable as `dt1` points at. So you only have one `DataTable` instance there.

Use the `Copy()` method of `DataTable` to make a new instance of the table, i.e. `dt2 = dt1.Copy();`

Answer (score 1):

Since DataTable is reference type you need to use one of the following options:

```
DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();
```

OR

```
DataTable dt2 = dt1.Copy();
```

see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dt2 = dt1;
```

By doing this you are introducing a new reference to the DataTable which was initially created as dt1. So you have single DataTable object instance in the memory and two references to it.

```
dt2.Columns.Add();
```

Updates this single DataTable instance and you can see this update when accessing it by any associated reference.